# Calculating fold change for each element between data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 data frames of equal number of columns and rows (NxM). I'm looking to calculate fold change element-wise. So as to each element in data frame 2 gets subtracted with the corresponding element in data frame 1 and divided by the corresponding element in data frame 1. I'm leaving 2 example data frames below with only 2 columns but my data frames have 150 columns and 1000 rows. I'm having trouble writing code for it.

| Col 1. | Col 2. |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | 3. |
| 4. | 5. |
| 7. | 1. |
| 1. | 9. |

| Col 1. | Col 2. |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | 3. |
| 4. | 5. |
| 1. | 5. |
| 7. | 1. |

This is what ive been doing to subtract them:

```
#bootstrapping all columns
df_sub1 = data1.sample( axis='rows',  n=1000, replace = True, ignore_index = True)
df_sub7 = data7.sample( axis='rows',  n=1000, replace = True, ignore_index = True)
#subtracting data frames element-wise
df_fc = df_sub7.sub(df_sub1)
```

How could I go about turning this snippet into fold change for each element? Thank you!

Comment: so, if i read this right, you've figured out how to do element wise subtraction, and are wondering how element wise division would work?

Comment: Yes I think that would work! @HaleemurAli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element wise division between two dataframes can be expressed as `df1 / df2`. note however, that pandas will attempt to align the indexes. this is not an issue if the dataframes are identically indexed.

using the sample data provided.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'c1': [1,4,7,1],
  'c2': [3,5,1,9]
  })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'c1': [1,4,1,7],
  'c2': [3,5,5,1]
  })

folded = (df2 - df1) / df1
# alternatively:
folded = df2.sub(df1).div(df1)
```

folded has the following values

```
         c1        c2
0  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.000000  0.000000
2 -0.857143  4.000000
3  6.000000 -0.888889
```